# JS calculate false hits to determine percentage

Tags: javascript, loops, counter

So my end-goal is to be able to calculate a match-maker for hotels and users. I will have question for the user to input via prompts, with which I will use to match up to the hotel details I provide and output to show which hotels are best suited to the user. At present my queries are:

```
//Hotel choices
const minStar = prompt("What is the minimum star rating you would like?");
if (minStar==5)
    {console.log(`That sounds grand`);}
else
    {console.log(`Just ${minStar}, huh?`);}
const distCityMax = prompt("What is the furthest distance in miles from a city you would be happy with?");
console.log(`${distCityMax} miles maximum from a city`);
const wifi = prompt("Do you require WiFi?");
console.log(`Do you require wifi? ${minStar}`);
const swimPool = prompt("Is a swimming pool important?");
console.log(`Your decision on a swimming pool was: ${swimPool}`);
```

With which I currently have to find just the matchings of one example hotel:

```
let passed=true;

if(minStar!=5){
    passed=false;
}
if(distCityMax>=1){
    passed=false;
}   
if(wifi!=="yes"){
    passed=false;
}
if(swimPoo!=="yes"){
    passed=false;
}

if(passed===true){
    console.log("These hotels would suit you: TheGrand");
}else{
    console.log("There are no matching hotels");
}
```

But I am having trouble figuring out, even after trying similar things posted across the forum, how to be able to count all the times a 'false' is hit so that I can count them and present a percentage with them.

tldr; how do I count the number of times "passed=false"?

Comment: Just create a variable and increment the count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use counter instead of the true/false flag:

```
let count = 0;

if (minStar != 5) {
    count++;
}
if (distCityMax >= 1) {
    count++;
}
if (wifi !== "yes") {
    count++;
}
if (swimPoo !== "yes") {
    count++;
}

console.log("Percentage of 'false': " + Math.round(100 * count / 4));

if (count === 0) {
    console.log("These hotels would suit you: TheGrand");
} else {
    console.log("There are no matching hotels");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this alternate and effective solution!